# User-Defined Aggregate Functions in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know how to create User-Defined Aggregate Functions which should do exactly the same job such as my stored procedure. My function should contain two input attributes, there are price and timer. (Sorry for my bad english)

My procedure is:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "PRICE"
  (key IN NUMBER) AS
   pricer ARTICLE.PRICE%type;
   BEGIN
   SELECT price INTO pricer
    FROM HistoryPrice
   WHERE Key_article =key  AND TIMER=(select max(TIMER) FROM 
   HistoryPrice WHERE Key_article=key AND TIMER<=SYSDATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Format will be like below. You need to change logic of select statement.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE function f_price
  (p_price IN NUMBER,
  p_timer in number
  ) return number as
   pricer ARTICLE.PRICE%type;
   BEGIN

   SELECT price INTO pricer
    FROM HistoryPrice
   WHERE Key_article =key  AND TIMER=(select max(TIMER) FROM 
   HistoryPrice WHERE Key_article=key AND TIMER<=SYSDATE);

   return pricer;

   end;
```

Comment: I need to create user defined agregate function. Example is below on the link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm